# Why can't Boruto use Odama Rasengan & Taju Kage Bunshin?

Tags: naruto, boruto

When Boruto was practicing to enhance his skill in episode 16x Kakashi mentioned that he can't create Odama Rasengan because he has low Chakra reserved. Likewise, several previous episodes also mentioned that he cant create even more than 10 Shadow Clone.

Kakashi explained that Naruto can do it because he is a Jinjuriki. Now, that is a bit contradicting since Konohamaru can actually do Odama and Taju as seen in episode of chunin exam between Konohamaru and Naruto.

So, why can't Boruto use Odama Rasengan & Taju Kage Bunshin? But Konohamaru can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching your question, I can see why there is confusion on to why Konohamaru "can" use these justus while Boruto cannot. Unfortunately the simple explanation is "because it's not-cannon"

When it comes to cannon, it is undetermined if Konohamaru can actually use either Big-Ball Rasengan or Multi-Shadow Clone Justu. The only appearances of him using these justus are in filler episodes<sup>1</sup> and an OVA<sup>2</sup>.

While it been stated before that Konohamaru and Boruto both have large charka reserves, Kakashi seems to be implying that it is not enough to safely perform either justu without the charka provided by a tailed beast. By safely, I refer to the reason why the Multi-Shadow Clone justu was marked as forbidden for being a risk to the user's life due to exerting too much chakra

---

<sup>1</sup> [Naruto's Favourite Pupil](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Naruto%27s_Favourite_Pupil)

<sup>2</sup> [Chūnin Exam on Fire! Naruto vs. Konohamaru!](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ch%C5%ABnin_Exam_on_Fire!_Naruto_vs._Konohamaru!)